# Issue with ViewBinding and custom Views

Tags: android, android-viewbinding

Lets assume that we have a following **foo.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/zzz"
    android:background="#f0f"
    ...
    >
```

and a extended LinearLayout called **SuperLinearLayout.kt**

```
class SuperLinearLayout: LinearLayout {
...
    val view = View.inflate(context, R.layout.foo, this)
    binding = FooBinding.bind(view)
...
    
}
```

then somewhere in the **SuperLinearLayout.kt**

```
val a1 = findViewById<LinearLayout>(R.id.zzz)
val a2 = binding.zzz
val a3 = binding.root
```

output:

```
a1 -> android.widget.LinearLayout{eabfd59... 
a1.background -> ColorDrawable@32089ff
a2 -> test.SuperLinearLayout{234fb46...
a2.background -> null
a3 -> test.SuperLinearLayout{234fb46...
a3.background -> null
```

why does the **a1** reference the correct **LinearLayout** View with correct background *ColorDrawable* when **a2** references the same object as **a3** with both showing *null* background (**a2** & **a3** both reference the **SuperLinearLayout**)?

I've checked the generated binding and I've found that:

```
@NonNull
public static FooBinding bind(@NonNull View rootView) {
...
    LinearLayout zzz = (LinearLayout) rootView;
...
}
```

Why am I loosing access to the correct View in my Layout hierarchy when using ViewBinding?

Answer (score 0):

Ehh. I've found the issue which was related to me simply putting wrong view when binding.